# Extrar elementos de array

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un ecommerce con javascript y se me ha presentado un problema ¿cómo podría hacer para extraer solo los **precios** de los productos del array **aRelojes** y guardarlos en otro array?.

```
let aRelojes = [{
        id: 1,
        marca: 'Rolex',
        imagen: `./img/rolex/oyster_perpetual_41.jpg`,
        nombre: 'Oyster Perpetual 41',
        categoria: 'Hombre',
        precio: 6400,
        descripcion: 'La estética de los modelos Oyster Perpetual los diferencia de los demás como símbolos de estilo clásico y universal. Respetando la línea de los orígenes pioneros de Rolex, encarnan la forma y función atemporales.',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        marca: 'Rolex',
        imagen: `./img/rolex/lady_datejust.jpg`,
        nombre: 'Lady Datejust',
        categoria: 'Mujer',
        precio: 41250,
        descripcion: 'Los reflejos luminosos sobre las asas y los flancos de la carrura resaltan las refinadas formas de su caja Oyster de 28 mm, coronada con un biselengastado de diamantes. Arquetipo del clásico femenino de Rolex, el Lady‑Datejust pertenece a la línea del Datejust, modelo emblemático que impuso su estilo y sus prestaciones relojeras.',
    },
    {
        estado: 'Nuevo',
        id: 3,
        marca: 'Rolex',
        imagen: `./img/rolex/datejust_41.jpg`,
        nombre: 'Datejust 41',
        categoria: 'Hombre',
        precio: 14300,
        descripcion: 'Los reflejos luminosos sobre las asas y los flancos de la carrura resaltan las refinadas formas de su caja Oyster 41 mm, coronada con un bisel estriado. En lo referente a la estética, el Datejust ha conservado con el paso de los años los códigos inmutables que aún hoy en día hacen de él, en su versión tradicional, uno de los relojes más reconocidos y reconocibles.',
    },
];
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado al momento?

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)

> El método map() crea un nuevo array con los resultados de la llamada a la función indicada aplicados a cada uno de sus elementos

```
const precios = aRelojes.map(el => el.precio)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer iterando sobre el arreglo que estas usando para almacenar toda la información, en este caso `aRelojes`, para ello la forma mas simple es con un [`for(i in array)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in) con lo cual obtienes los indicies, una vez que ya los tienes accedes al indicie del arreglo haciendo uso de `aRelojes[i]` con lo cual te va a mostrar todos los `json` del arreglo, para acceder a los valores de las claves deberas hacer uso del operador punto `.` de la siguiente manera `aRelojes[i].precio` y eso nada mas lo añades a un arreglo vacío, te dejo el codigo completo abajo.

```js
let aRelojes = [{
        id: 1,
        marca: 'Rolex',
        imagen: `./img/rolex/oyster_perpetual_41.jpg`,
        nombre: 'Oyster Perpetual 41',
        categoria: 'Hombre',
        precio: 6400,
        descripcion: 'La estética de los modelos Oyster Perpetual los diferencia de los demás como símbolos de estilo clásico y universal. Respetando la línea de los orígenes pioneros de Rolex, encarnan la forma y función atemporales.',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        marca: 'Rolex',
        imagen: `./img/rolex/lady_datejust.jpg`,
        nombre: 'Lady Datejust',
        categoria: 'Mujer',
        precio: 41250,
        descripcion: 'Los reflejos luminosos sobre las asas y los flancos de la carrura resaltan las refinadas formas de su caja Oyster de 28 mm, coronada con un biselengastado de diamantes. Arquetipo del clásico femenino de Rolex, el Lady‑Datejust pertenece a la línea del Datejust, modelo emblemático que impuso su estilo y sus prestaciones relojeras.',
    },
    {
        estado: 'Nuevo',
        id: 3,
        marca: 'Rolex',
        imagen: `./img/rolex/datejust_41.jpg`,
        nombre: 'Datejust 41',
        categoria: 'Hombre',
        precio: 14300,
        descripcion: 'Los reflejos luminosos sobre las asas y los flancos de la carrura resaltan las refinadas formas de su caja Oyster 41 mm, coronada con un bisel estriado. En lo referente a la estética, el Datejust ha conservado con el paso de los años los códigos inmutables que aún hoy en día hacen de él, en su versión tradicional, uno de los relojes más reconocidos y reconocibles.',
    },
];

let precios=[];

for(i in aRelojes){
   precios.push(aRelojes[i].precio);
}

console.info(precios)
```